# Why does crontab throw error: "illegal action"

Tags: cron

I entered some cron jobs, everything saved correctly (jobs added)
I then went back and typed crontab -e to adjust something and I got a message: "illegal action" I also get this when typing crontab --help or crontab

Wow...now when I open my terminal, I get:

Could not open a new pseudo-tty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input :). I restarted my computer and everything is working again. Go fig...

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e` tries to use the editor specified in your environment variable named `VISUAL` (or missing that in the one named `EDITOR`).  What do you have in those variables?  It's impossible for us to guess, but maybe it's some weird value causing the "illegal action" message and/or something that consumes all pseudo-ttys, causing the rest of the problems you report.

`crontab --help`, to *me*, says "illegal option" (**not** "illegal action"!), but that's on my Darwin machine -- you don't deign to mention what version of Unix-oid system you're using and, again, it's impossible to guess from your scant input!-)